# cmd run part of script in other console

Tags: cmd

How can I run a part of script in other cmd console [wait for finish] after return to first console and continue script?

eg script

```
REM [PART 1] start
echo test
echo test 2
echo test 3
REM [PART 1] stop

REM [PART 2] start in other CMD and wait for finish
echo test 4
echo test 5
echo test 6
unzip test 7
REM [PART 2] stop

REM [PART 1] start again
echo ***script finish***
exit
REM [PART 1] stop / finish
```

I want to execute eg this part of script in other cmd console and wait for finish script after return to first console and finish.

```
echo test 4
echo test 5
echo test 6
unzip test 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two seperate cmd files e.g. test1.cmd and test2.cmd. If you want to run test2.cmd from test1.cmd within a new window you have to start a new command processor `cmd` in test1.cmd using the `start` command:

```
start "Test" /wait cmd /c test2.cmd
```

The `/wait` parameter makes the start command to wait until the second process finishes. You can also look for the help of the `start` command for the parameters.